# C# IronPDF send plain text to a PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm using Visual Studio, C# and IronPDF is installed OK.

Sample PDF working

```
IronPdf.HtmlToPdf Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
HtmlToPdf HtmlToPdf = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
Renderer.RenderUrlAsPdf("http://www.google.com/").SaveAs("google.com.pdf");
```

I can't find any info on IronPDF documentation about how to send plain text to the PDF.

**How can I send by example "Hello world" to a new PDF? Or IronPDF only works with HTML?**

Note: I only have limited experience with iTextSharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do not convert Text to html and send it ?

```
public static Byte[] HtmlToPdf()
{
  var Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
  var PDF = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf("<p>Any TEXT</p>" );
  return PDF.Stream.ToArray();
}
```